# Couchbase gocb bulk operation delivers partially empty results

Tags: go, couchbase, gocb

In our go code using gocb we're querying a view that returns 32k ids. We then perform a bulk query (see code below) like explained in a [CouchBase blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/bulk-operations-using-couchbase-and-golang/). However, we only get partial results. We can see that `ruleset, _ := items[i].(*gocb.GetOp).Value.(*RuleSet)`only returns a value for the first 2048 ids. Then the ids 2049 - 11322 do not contain a value and so on. Our result looks like so:

```
Line 1 Key: 12345678901234567890123456789012, Value: map[0.0.0.0/0:map[jsona:valueofjsona]]
...
Line 2018 Key: 12345678901234567890123456712345, Value: map[0.0.0.0/0:map[jsona:valueofjsona]]
Line 2019 Key: 12345678901234567890123456712345, Value: map[]
...
Line 11323 Key: 12345678901234567890123456712347, Value: map[jsonb:valueofjsonb]]
```

(The above lines are simplified, the keys don't match actual data, nor does the value.)

A huge portion of the requested data is not actually returned:

```
CB# grep '\[\]' result.out |wc -l
27042
CB# wc -l result.out
31988 rdmp.out
```

Does `bucket.do` return before it has completed processing all queries? We looked at the API code and could not find an explanation.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
type RuleSet struct {
    Rules map[string]interface{} "json:\"rules,\""
}

func DiffViaBulkQuery() {
  var items []gocb.BulkOp
  var row interface{}
  var cnt int = 0
  bucket := cbase.MyBucket()

// [...]
// add 600k entries to itemsget in a loop like 
// itemsGet = append(itemsGet, &gocb.GetOp{Key: key + "_" + strconv.Itoa(i), Value: &Doc{}})


// Perform the bulk operation to Get all documents
  err = bucket.Do(itemsGet)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERRROR PERFORMING BULK GET:", err)
  }

// Print the output
  for i := 0; i < len(itemsGet); i++ {
    fmt.Println(itemsGet[i].(*gocb.GetOp).Key, itemsGet[i].(*gocb.GetOp).Value.(*Doc).Item)
  }
```

Thx in advance,
Torsten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth checking the error value for each of the operations that you are performing. You can do this by doing `op.Err` so, for example, that'd be

```
    for i := 0; i < len(items); i++ {
    fmt.Println(items[i].(*gocb.GetOp).Key, items[i].(*gocb.GetOp).Value.(*Doc).Item, items[i].(*gocb.GetOp).Err)
}
```

I expect that what you'll see is that you're hitting `queue overflowed` errors which happens the gocb dispatcher queue becomes full, it defaults to a max size of 2048 items. The solution is usually to perform the work in smaller batches so as not to overload gocb. There is a similar issue with an example on https://forums.couchbase.com/t/bulk-upsert-data-into-couchbase/17354/2